# Assigning bool value in method doesn´t work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods, boolean

I´ve made a small arcade-style game in which a bool-variable keeps track of whether the game is over or not (gameOver).

```
private bool gameOver;
```

When an obstacle hits the player, the following method is executed:

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    //GameOver
    gameOver = true;
}
```

The next method should increase the score only if the value of gameOver is equal to false.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (!gameOver)
    {
        if (int.Parse(scoreText.text) == 0)
        {
            scoreText.text = "1";
        }
        else if (int.Parse(scoreText.text) > 0)
        {
            int oldNumber = int.Parse(scoreText.text);
            int newNumber = oldNumber + 1;
            scoreText.text = newNumber.ToString();
        }
    }
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

But when the game is actually "lost", the score stays increasing.
I logged the value of gameOver at different times and it seems that the value of gameOver is set to true in the OnCollisionEnter2D method, but when logged in the OnTriggerEnter2D method, it says false. I tried to assign the value in a seperate method with the out-Keyword, but that didn´t work, too. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which method is triggered first? Is it OnCollisionEnter2D or OnTriggerEnter2D?

Comment: Seems like your events are triggered in reverse order, first the `Enter2D` and then `Collision`.

Comment: Did you try to make it static?  You are probably creating a new instance of the class when a new game occurs and it is being set to default.

Comment: @Reniuz/HimBromBeere, according to the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), first OnTriggerXXX is called and then OnCollisionXXX

Comment: @jdweng Using `static` in Unity isn't the best idea and normally means you don't know how to work with Unity properly. We don't have enough information here, but the correct way is to have some class that lasts as long as a `static` field was meant to last, which could be until the game is closed

Answer (score 1):

You didn't change gameOver bool in a global state and only one obstacle know that you lose. The easiest solution:

```
private static bool gameOver;
```

Another solution is to store gameOver in the GameManager singleton if you are using it

You also can store this state in one static class:

```
public static class GameStates
{
    public static bool IsGameOver = false;
    public static int Score = 0;
    //other global states
}
```

And use it without problems:

```
if (!GameStates.IsGameOver)
{
    //do something
}
```

If you don't want to use static (it's not the best solution in unity) - use singleton (don't make complex architecture for small game)

Comment: Thank you it worked! I think that sounds like a dumb question, but how do I make a Singleton?

Comment: @TitanTomato A singleton is just a design pattern whereby you insure that only one instance of a given class exists. *How* you do that is an implementation detail.

Comment: @TitanTomato you can use this one https://github.com/caxapexac/UnityTemplates/blob/master/Scripts/Singleton.cs